# First line of answer only visible

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, disputed-flags

I recently flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360074/json-parsing-to-get-lat-long/24360173#24360173) as Not an Answer. When I viewed the answer in question it had just been posted (some 45 secs previously I think). All I saw in the answer was the first line:

> FYI, the response JSON is an Object, not an Array.

Accordingly I flagged for not being an answer to the question.
Some hours later when I checked, the text in the answer had increased although no edits had been made to the post, and accordingly my flag was correctly disputed.

My question is why did I only see the first line of the answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a 5 minute grace period where edits are not recorded in the post revisions.

If within 5 minutes of posting an answer the OP edits it, those edits get rolled into the original revision.

Unfortunately some people abuse the grace period to get the first answer in.

Comment: It would be nice if you could add the status-bydesign tag after answering the question, I was for a moment like **WTF?**. Related to the abusal, some people think it is the only way to get the rep they deserve: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that you saw it less than 5 minutes after the post was submitted.  Then, they added more.

If their addition was within 5 minutes of answering, the edit does not show up in the edit history.  This is called a "grace period."